# I need a guide about Screen Tracking in Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am trying to set Screen Tracking in my App.

As far as I understand, It requires each different window to track user's activity.

Here is my question.

Can I set different Screen Tracking code in Pop-up window(Example: Store Pop-up)? Or do I need to make a whole- different window to track user's activity properly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually track screens by calling `Analytics.setScreenName(screenName, screenClass: screenClass)`.

For more on this see the Firebase documentation on [tracking screenviews](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews). You can also find examples in other languages there.

Comment: Always I appreciate your answer!